# Tyrus Websockets Android: Failed resolving Lorg/glassfish/tyrus/core/OsgiRegistry

Tags: android, websocket, tyrus

I use the tyrus-standalone-client.jar version -1.10 for my Android app to use web sockets.

My stack trace is as follows:

```
04-16 21:31:42.917 D/ACRA    (24960): ACRA is enabled for     com.tely.device.application.gcalsync, intializing...

04-16 21:31:42.917 I/dalvikvm(24181): Failed resolving Lorg/glassfish/tyrus/core/OsgiRegistry; interface 4566 'Lorg/osgi/framework/SynchronousBundleListener;'

04-16 21:31:42.917 W/dalvikvm(24181): Link of class' Lorg/glassfish/tyrus/core/OsgiRegistry;' failed

04-16 21:31:42.917 I/dalvikvm(24181): Could not find method org.glassfish.tyrus.core.OsgiRegistry.getInstance, referenced from method org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ReflectionHelper.getOsgiRegistryInstance

04-16 21:31:42.917 W/dalvikvm(24181): VFY: unable to resolve static method 35259: Lorg/glassfish/tyrus/core/OsgiRegistry;.getInstance ()Lorg/glassfish/tyrus/core/OsgiRegistry;
04-16 21:31:42.917 D/dalvikvm(24181): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0008
04-16 21:31:42.917 I/dalvikvm(24181): Failed resolving Lorg/glassfish/tyrus/core/OsgiRegistry; interface 4566 'Lorg/osgi/framework/SynchronousBundleListener;'
```

Researching a bit, some sources say that the version of the jar could be unstable. So, I tried with 1.9 and 1.8.3. The problem is not resolved. Please suggest any stable version or any thoughts on what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Pavel Bucek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/945485/pavel-bucek) you can ignore this exception, .
See https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/websocket_client_on_android_tyrus or https://java.net/jira/browse/TYRUS-392